# Retrieve XML attribute value

Tags: xml, vba, excel

Using the following XML document:

http://www.broadbandmap.gov/broadbandmap/census/block?latitude=40.784045&longitude=-73.845828&format=xml

I want to get the value `"360050216022002"` from the node:

```
<block FIPS="360050216022002">
```

Here is the code in VBA, but the number is not in a node so I cannot use
`SelectNodes`.

How can I change the code?

```vb
Function GetCensusTrack(lat As String, lon As String) As String

' Requires a reference to Microsoft XML, v6.0'


    Dim myRequest As XMLHTTP60
    Dim blockNode As IXMLDOMNode ' Can I set it as Node?'

    Dim uu As String

    Set myRequest = New XMLHTTP60

    uu = "http://www.broadbandmap.gov/broadbandmap/census/block?latitude=" & lat & "&longitude=" & lon & "&format=xml"
    myRequest.Open "GET", uu, False
    myRequest.send

   If myRequest.readyState = 4 Then
    Set myDomDoc = New DOMDocument60

   myDomDoc.LoadXML myRequest.responseText
' Get the latitude and longitude node values'
```

' what should I type here?'
        Set blockNode = ????
      End If
    End Function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FIPS` is an attribute of `<block>`. You can use `@` to specify that you want to query an attribute:

```vb
Dim a As Object
Set a = myDomDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Response/Results/block/@FIPS")

If Not a Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "Attribute value = " & a.Text
End If
```